# Using methods in a class which requires an argument for a constructor (Bukkit plugin)

Tags: java, constructor, minecraft, bukkit

I'm writing a plugin for CraftBukkit and have gotten to the stage of splitting up classes and methods into separate files for organisation. The problem I have is I need to pass Plugin to other classes in order to use its methods. Example:

**SimpleBans.java**

```
public class SimpleBans extends JavaPlugin {
    private final DatabaseManager dm = new DatabaseManager(this);
}
```

**DatabaseManager.java**

```
public class DatabaseManager {
    private Plugin plugin;
    public DatabaseManager(SimpleBans pluginConstructor) {
        plugin = pluginConstructor;
    }

public void writeData(String SQL) {
    // Pseudo code: Write plugin.getName(); into the database.
}
```

Now that works fine. However, if I want to use the `writeData` method from another class, I don't have anything to pass as an argument e.g:

**PlayerListener.java**

```
public class PlayerListener {
    private final DatabaseManager dm = new DatabaseManager(SOMETHINGGOESHERE);
}
```

I cannot use null in this either as it has to be a Plugin to match the constructor arguments within `DatabaseManager.java`.

This has been bugging me for ages. Any help would be well welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try and create a new `DatabaseManager` inside `PlayerListener`. Instead, take a `DatabaseManager` as a constructor argument for the listener class. This way, you can use your already-constructed `DatabaseManager` when you create the listener.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a constructor with null arguments? Is there a reason? Your class would then be...

```
public class DatabaseManager {
    private Plugin plugin;

    public DatabaseManager() {
        this.plugin = new SimpleBeans();
    }

    public DatabaseManager(SimpleBans pluginConstructor) {
        plugin = pluginConstructor;
    }

    public void writeData(String SQL) {
        // Pseudo code: Write plugin.getName(); into the database.
    }

    ...
}
```

Then the `DatabaseManager` could be instantiated using both ways.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

Create method like the following inside `DatabaseManager`:

```
public class DatabaseManager {

    public static DatabaseManager initManager() {
        SimpleBans simpleBans = new SimpleBans(); //Or however you construct it
        return new DatabaseManager(simpleBans);
    }

}
```

Then in your other classes, simply call:

```
private final DatabaseManager dm = DatabaseManager.initManager();
```

I believe this is a type of design pattern, but I forget its name.